# Convert CSV files into OSM with FME

Tags: python, openstreetmap, fme-form, csv

I have a database which i've exported as individual csv files for each table.

Below are some of the attributes which exist from two of the csv files:

```
wayPointID  linkID  order   x   y   z   length  radius
```

and

```
nodeID  x   y   z   name    description type
```

I'm in need of a method to convert this data into osm.

When I attempt just csv -> osm  in fme, of course the output is only the osm xml headers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I have been able to use 2DPointReplacer to take the x and y attributes and it successfully outputs nodes.

However, he data I have does require the tables be joined in order to build  attributes. Because of this I have to create a new id to each position and be ordered/continued across several tables.

I have written a python script which will do what I need but would like this done in FME.

Can anyone offer suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To join the tables use featureMerger using the ID as key match.
To create ID's use the counter.

hope it helps
Regards
Jorge Vidinha

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've implement the Counter transformer to create a new id for each position across two datasets. I notice however when it writes to the file from the counter output, the ordering of the positions, switches from dataset to dataset, like it was 'simulatneous processing', process 1 from dataset 1 then process from dataset 2. Can this be forced to finish one dataset at a time?

Comment: Yes you can force FME to read your datasets one after the other, on the navigator right click on the readers and chose move up or down on the list , fme reads datasets from top to botom then counter as first transformer in workspace shoudl make the count as you describe. good luck. Jorge Vidinha

Answer (score 1):

You better off converting your csv file to shapefile [it uses python]

Then you can use
[Shp2osm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shp2osm)

*"This article is about the shp2osm.pl and polyshp2osm.py family of conversion scripts which convert shapefiles to OSM files. For the general process regarding importing shapefiles along with alternative scripts "*

more details on Christopher Schmidt (the author of Shposm) blog

http://crschmidt.net/blog/archives/354/polyshp2osm/

Comment: hi, I have tried exporting into shape and it was successful when only doing points. When it comes to lines, it's more difficult because in my datasets, a line is comprised of data from multiple datasets/multiple csv files.